# SpriteKit SKPhysicsContact Issue

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

In a game I'm making I am having an issue where when my player & coin come into contact with one another they collide then the coin rolls right off & then deletes itself from the game scene. The way I want it to work is when the coin collides with my player, it would count as 1 point & to have the coin delete itself upon them making contact. This is the code I have so far

Comment: Set the collision bit masks to 0. If you're not getting a contact notification, make sure you've set `physicsWorld.contactDelegate`. Also, I don't see where you're setting the node names, so maybe the contact is happening and you're just missing it because the ordering and/or checking for names is wrong.

Comment: @bg2b I set my player & background sprite nodes inside of my game scene  my coin is inside of an objc function though could that have something to do with it ?

Comment: Shouldn't matter. You can turn on `showsPhysics` in the scene to see the physics bodies, and you can set a breakpoint in `didBegin` to make sure that it's being called at all. If it's not, likely problems are either the `physicsWorld.contactDelegate` not set, both bodies having `isDynamic` set to `false` (at least one must be `true` for collisions to be flagged), or the categories/bitmasks wrong.

Comment: Does your player have a name?  I am going to guess your did contact is not working because you do not have any name for player, so the collision code is kicking in.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I just added the player name I did not do that before that was a mistake I made but the coin is still not deleting from the player, at this point I'm very confused, I even swapped to using enums & the cases for the physics but I just get the same results

Comment: Does your coin move?

Comment: Yeah I have my coin set on a timer it drops from the top of the screen @Knight0fDragon

Comment: take out `if secondNode.name == "playernode"` and just leave the removeFromParent code.  if it works, then it means you have an issue with the name

Comment: I did that now & nothing unfortunately, do you think the issue could be that my coin information is not inside the did move to view ? its in an objc function inside of the class because when I tried adding it to the did move it conflicts with the timer @Knight0fDragon

Comment: post your code, the actual code being used.

Comment: Alright I'll edit the question now @Knight0fDragon

Comment: your didbegin is all lowercase

Comment: @Knight0fDragon what is supposed to be capitalized ? I'm very new I apologize

Comment: `func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)`

Comment: Thank you for that, can't believe I missed it but the coin still isn't being deleted upon contact with the player @Knight0fDragon

Comment: you are doing coin width / 6 for a body,  Perhaps you are just missing it because it is so tiny

Comment: I've tried changing the size too it still collides with the player no problem its just the deletion I'm having an issue with upon when they collide, do you think maybe if I removed the delete action from the coin it would make a difference @Knight0fDragon

Comment: You are missing a brace before your didBegin  it is right now in the touchmoved function

Comment: Thank you so much !!!!! @Knight0fDragon that solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very important to keep your code aligned, and to keep an eye on capitalization since since swift is case sensitive.

The errors in this code were player missing a name, a missing brace at the end of touchesMoved, and the didBegin being all lowercase.

Hopefully this will be a lesson in code management.

Comment: can I ask you one last question ? I feel bad for bothering you but I need help with one last thing